# Transaction becomes null after SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar is run

Tags: c#, sqlclient

I have a table in SQL Server defined as follows

```
create table Customer (ID varchar(10), Name varchar(200))

Insert into Customer 
values ('00001', 'Cust1'), ('ID00002', 'Cust2')
```

When I query customer name using ID (with wrong datatype, it is `varchar`, but its value is passed as `int`), the command returns correct name, but its transaction becomes null, and on trying to commit, I get an error

> InvalidOperationException
>   This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.

My code:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (var trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM Customer WHERE ID = 1")) // After this command is executed, its transaction becomes null.
        //using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM Customer  WHERE ID = '000001'")) // This runs fine.
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.Transaction = trans;
            var res = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }

        trans.Commit(); 
    }
}
```

Is there anything I can do to check such scenario, and fail it when the command executes, instead of getting exception at later stage?

Comment: what is value of your `res` after execution?

Comment: Why would you even need to pass wrong datatype value?

Comment: @SeM-ՍեՄ, value of res is valid customer name. Actually, wrong datatype was passed by mistake.

Answer (score -1):

ISNUMERIC returns 1 when the input expression evaluates to a valid numeric data type; otherwise it returns 0.

You Try This Code

```
  using (var conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SchoolPlusDBContext"].ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (var trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM Customer where  ISNUMERIC(id)=1 and Id=1")) // After this command is executed, its transaction becomes null.
                //using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM Customer  WHERE ID = '000001'")) // This runs fine.
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.Transaction = trans;
                    var res = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                }

                trans.Commit();
            }
        }
```

Comment: this solves the issue but correct solution would be to pass data as correct datatype. However, my query is if the command execution can be failed in such scenario when the command runs.